# Spring boot save assigning a student to a group

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a problem with my spring boot simple application. I create a student's diary. I have function to assign student to group. I create in thymeleaf view seen below:

```html
<form name="myForm" method="post">
  <div class="row" id="groupList">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="form-group blu-margin" th:object="${group}">
        <select class="form-control" id="dropGroup">
          <option value="0">Wybierz grupę : </option>
          <option th:each="group : ${groupList}" th:value="${group.name}" th:text="${group.name}">
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="form-group blu-margin" th:object="${user}">
        <select class="form-control" id="dropGroup">
          <option value="0">Wybierz studenta : </option>
          <option th:each="user : ${userListNew}" th:value="${user.firstName}" th:text="${user.firstName}+ ' ' +${user.lastName}">
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My model class User and Group:

**Group:**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
private List<User> users;
```

**User:**

```
@ManyToOne
private Group group;
```

And this is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showGroupList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showGroupList(Model model){
    List<Group> groupList = groupRepository.findAll();
    List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER");
    List<User> userListNew = new ArrayList<>();

    for (User user : userList){
        if (user.getRoles().contains(userRole)){
            userListNew.add(user);
        }
    }

    model.addAttribute("groupList", groupList);
    model.addAttribute("userListNew", userListNew);
    return "groupList";
}
```

Now, when I select group and user from their list and click submit I have the following error:

> WARN 1132 --- [nio-8070-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue of the method you wish to use in your form. Your error is:

```
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

It says clearly that your application doesn't know how to handle Post requests, and you asked to POST a form. In the top of the form you ask for POST http method:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post">
```

However in the controller layer you only specify GET http method:

```
method = RequestMethod.GET
```

You can resolve this by doing one of two options: Change the form to Get, or specify in the controller what to do when you send a POST request. Looking at your application, I would guess that you want to first call GET to get the list and maybe POST when you submit - but it's a question of the design you prefer.

In order to add a POST controller, maybe something like this would work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity <String> persistGroup(@RequestBody Group group) {
    groupRepository.save(group);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
}
```

you will need to test with your specific implementation to see what the form takes as a body (it may not be Group) and see which URI it goes to ("/" may not be the correct URI). The idea is that you save the Group or User into their respective repositories.

Comment: Yes, in my project first i would to like get all group and student who do not have a group. And leter I wants to save it to the database. I my user table i have column group_id,but now is null.

Comment: If that's the case, you will need to implement both changes: specify in the controller a POST handler, so you can take care of the eventual POST; and also add a GET in your form to retrieve the lists.

Comment: @mattt, if you feel like I answered your question, would you consider accepting it by clicking the gray check mark on its left, making it green?

Comment: ok, so what can a post controller look like that will assign a student to a group??

Comment: You will need to go by this example: https://dzone.com/articles/simple-spring-boot-post. I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a form in your HTML, in order to send a post, or you can send it using `jQuery` or `JS`, but that would be adding additional complicities to your code. After adding your form, you will ned to add a method to catch that request.

**HTML**

```
<form th:action="@{/assign-group}" th:object="${newUser}" method="post">
    <select class="form-control" id="dropGroup" th:field="*{group.id}">
        <option value="0">Wybierz grupę : </option>
        <option th:each="selectedGroup : ${groupList}" th:value="${selectedGroup.id}" th:text="${group.name}">
        </option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" id="dropGroup" th:field="*{id}">
        <option value="0">Wybierz studenta : </option>
        <option th:each="selectedUser : ${userList}" th:value="${selectedUser.id}" th:text="${user.name}">
        </option>
    </select>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

In this form you will be sending an User entity with it's id set and it's group id set as well. One more thing, you will see we are using `th:object="${newUser}"`, this means we need to create a `@ModelAttribute` in your controller, so that it returns a new user to your forms.

**CONTROLLER**

```
@ModelAttribute(value = "newUser")
public Store newUser() {return new User();}

@RequestMapping(value = "/assign-group", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String assignGroup(@ModelAttribute("newUser") User user) {
    // Fetch your the rest of the information using the id received.
    // Fetch the group using the group's id received.
    // Set this group to the fetched user.
}
```

If you need anything else, let me know.